# Return a shallow copy of an object in JpaRepository findAll() method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

I am trying to retrieve a list of entities using `JpaRepository`'s `findAll()` method, but the Entity that I am trying to retrieve has a number of other Objects as `OneToMany` Relationship inside it.

I have a class `Program` as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Program extends BaseEntity {

    private String programTitle;

    private String description;

    private String programType;

    private String price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "program-benefit")
    private List<Benefit> benefits = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;
    //Getters and setters
    }
```

As you can see, It has a list of `Benefits` in it.

When I am trying to retrieve Program, I am getting a JSON that has Both the objects list in it as well, Like:

**Response I am getting:**

```
{
    "id":1,
    "category": "cardio",
    "description": "exercies for cardio",
    "benefit": [
        {
            "description": "good for healt"
        },
        {
            "description": "string2"
        }
    ],
    "price": "50",
    "program_title": "cardio demo"
}
```

But I want a shallow copy of The object like

**Expected Response:**

```
{
    "id":1,
    "category": "cardio",
    "description": "exercies for cardio",
    "price": "50",
    "program_title": "cardio demo"
}
```

I tried changing `CascadeType` but it would stop showing nested objects in all APIs, I only want the nested objects to be removed when I call `findAll()` method.

Is there a way to stop showing nested objects when I call the `findAll()` method?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the not the findAll that's the problem... it's the JSON serialization, which forces the evaluation of the lazy fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two choices:

1. If you want to avoid serializing the fetched fields, use `@JsonIgnore`.
2. If you don't want to fetch those fields at all, create a DTO and write a custom query to map the results to it:

   ```
   public class ProgramDTO {

       private Long id;
       private String programTitle;
       private String description;
       private String programType;
       private String price;

   }
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   entityManager
       .createQuery("select new ProgramDTO(p.id, p.programTitle, p.description, p.programType, p.price from Program p")
       .getResultList();
   ```

Comment: It says : `Unable to locate class [ProgramDto]`

Comment: @RohanShah can you try it now?

Comment: @RohanShah also `ProgramDTO` needs to have an all args constructor